# When does fasting for Yom Kippur Katan officially begin and end?

Tags: fast-days, rosh-chodesh-new-month, yom-kippur-katan

I have been trying to find out the zmanim at which the Yom Kippur Katan fast begins and ends, however I have found a post on here [When does fasting Erev Rosh Hashanah officially begin and end?](https://udaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45742/when-does-fasting-erev-rosh-hashanah-officially-begin-and-end) which mentions Yom Kippur Katan in the question body, but I do not know if the answer also applies to Yom Kippur Katan.